# is there a way to store the whole text of an Android activity screen in a string or HTML format?

Tags: android

I have an activity within my application which displays the results of some calculation breakdown, I wanted to implement the functionality which would allow the user send the whole content of this screen by e-mail or at least be able to copy this content into the clipboard, I know I can use this snippet to send the e-mail:

```
    String subject = "subject";
    String body = "body"; // I need to store the content of the activity here

    Intent messageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    String aEmailList[] = { "some@etmail.com" };   
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, aEmailList);

    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);

    messageIntent.setType("text/html");
    messageIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body.toString()));

    startActivity(messageIntent);
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

How does the text get put onto the screen in the first place?

Just edit the methods that are generating text and putting it on the screen to also append it to a `StringBuilder` while its working then at the end you can call `builder.toString()` and it will contain all of the same information.